# Get all agent environments and versions using Google/Dialogflow API

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am using the google/dialogflow npm package to work with agents, entities etc using Node.js code according to this documentation https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest.

I have several environments (beta feature as of now) as well as several snapshotted versions. How can I via the google/dialogflow npm package retrieve specific environment/versions of the agent (or where can is the documentation for working with environments/versions via code/rest)? (list, get specific etc).